# Why is my game object moving when placed under new parent?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a deck of card objects in a panel. when i deal them out i have a lerping function attached. 3 out of 4 of the player panels the cards get dealt out to work perfectly and are just a plain panel they are being lerped to. they start from the deck pile and go to the hand pile. On the actual players hand i have Horizontal layout group. I am spawning and deleting empty panels into the horizontal group to be the parents of the cards. The problem is however, when i place the card to be the child of this panel in the horizontal group the cards position changes and jumps across the screen. I have no idea what is causing this jump. below is the code that spawns the parent panel followed by the card lerp.

Panel spawn

```
public Transform SpawnCardPanel()
{
    GameObject parent = Instantiate(Resources.Load<GameObject>("CardParentPanel"));
    parent.transform.SetParent(GameControl.Instance.localPlayerPanel.GetComponent<PanelControl>().handsInCardParent);
    parent.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
    parent.transform.position = Vector3.zero;
    return parent.transform;
}
```

The card lerp

```
public void StartLerping(Transform newParent, Vector3 endPoint) {
    isLerping = true;
    timeStartedLerping = Time.time;
    startParent = transform.parent;
    transform.SetParent(newParent, true);

    startPosition = transform.localPosition;
    endPosition = endPoint;
}

void Update() {
    if (isLerping)
    {
        float timeSinceStarted = Time.time - timeStartedLerping;
        float percentageComplete = timeSinceStarted / timeTakenDuringLerp;
        transform.localPosition = Vector3.Lerp(startPosition, endPosition, percentageComplete);

        if (percentageComplete >= timeTakenDuringLerp)
        {
            isLerping = false;
            Sounds.Instance.PlayCardFlip(transform.GetComponent<AudioSource>());
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You are altering the `localPositiin` in both cases, the `localPosition` is the delta offset to the parent so if you set it after assigning a new parent with a different position of course your object will move relative to that new parent ...

Comment: the local position is not altered until the update function. even then it starts at the variable start position that is set in the startlerping function. And that is set to where the object sits in relation to the new parent. this works in 3 out of 4 cases. I even got rid of the lerping just to try and get a better idea of what is happening. As soon i set the new parent, thats it, just setting the parent, the actual object just snaps to a different location. that is the problem I'm trying to solve, why is it snapping to the new location automatically.

Comment: So describe exactly which is the one case where it doesn't behave as expected. Also a `HorizontalLayoutGroup` makes it own arrangements to the child positions so it might act against yours ...

Comment: as i said in original post. in the three cases it works they are just lerping to a panel where they stack on top of each other, those would be the other players. on the panel that is goes wonky on i spawn that panel with that function above to be the parent. that way the horizontal layout shouldnt effect the lerping gameobject. however upon setting the cards parent to the panel the card snaps way out in right field and then lerps to proper location

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what exactly is happening here to cause this but i removed the horizontal layout group and the spawned panel. I then wrote custom code to give the same effect as the layout group.